# resolve dictionary key or parameter variable in Ansible

Tags: ansible

In Ansible, if I try to use a variable as a parameter name, or a key name, it is never resolved. For example, if I have `{{ some_var }}: true`, or:

```
template: "{{ resolve_me_to_src }}": "some_src"
```

the variables will just be used literally and never resolve. My specific use case is using this with the ec2 module, where some of my tag names are stored as variables:

```
- name: Provision a set of instances
  ec2:
    group: "{{ aws_security_group }}"
    instance_type: "{{ aws_instance_type }}"
    image: "{{ aws_ami_id }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ aws_vpc_subnet_id }}"
    key_name: "{{ aws_key_name }}"
    wait: true
    count: "{{ num_machines }}"
    instance_tags: { "{{ some_tag }}": "{{ some_value }}", "{{ other_tag }}": "{{ other_value }}" }
```

Is there any way around this? Can I mark that I want to force evaluation somehow?

Comment: What about creating a var that contains your tags instead? For example, instance_tags: {{ my_instance_tags }}

Comment: @jarv I'm 100% cool with that, but when creating the var I run into the exact same problems. Using `set_fact` to create the dictionary, it still doesn't process the keys as variables.

Comment: I would isolate your problem from the ec2 module, try adding a "- debug: var=my_instance_tags" before the ec2 task to see what Ansible has for the var.

Comment: I know what ansible has for the var. It's just got the unresolved variable. The whole issue is I don't know how to make it resolve any kind of keys in dictionaries as variables, regardless of where I create the dictionary.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
(rc=0)$ cat training.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tags: so5
  gather_facts: False
  vars: [
      k1: 'key1',
      k2: 'key2',
      d1: "{
        '{{k1}}': 'value1',
        '{{k2}}': 'value2',
      }",
    ]
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="{{item}}"
    with_dict: "{{d1}}"


(rc=0)$ ansible-playbook training.yml -t so5

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************** 

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************** 

TASK: [debug msg="{{item}}"] ************************************************** 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'key2', 'value': 'value2'}) => {
    "item": {
        "key": "key2", 
        "value": "value2"
    }, 
    "msg": "{'value': 'value2', 'key': 'key2'}"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'key1', 'value': 'value1'}) => {
    "item": {
        "key": "key1", 
        "value": "value1"
    }, 
    "msg": "{'value': 'value1', 'key': 'key1'}"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
localhost                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

(rc=0)$
```

Trick is to wrap dict declaration with double quotes. Ansible applies this undocumented (but consistant) and crappy translation (ansible's equivalent of shell variable expantion) to most (not all) YAML values (everything RHS of `':'`) in the playbook. It is some combination putting these strings through Jinja2-engine, Python-interpreter and ansible-engine in some unknown order.

Comment: Yes! This is incredible. How did you find how to do this? I looked everywhere and gave up on getting this to work months ago.

Comment: O I was frustrated with something similar and looked through the code to figure out how the hell does it expand vars.. :-)

Comment: Why it tells me: `FAILED! => {"msg": "with_dict expects a dict"}` ? it's like the double quotes is a string not a real dict

Comment: my first guess would be (as the message says), you're passing a variable that's not a `dict` to `with_dict`. In the example above, variable `d1` is a `dict`. Post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Another option - you can try something like:

```
  module_name: "{{ item.key }}={{ item.value }}"
  with_items:
  - { key: "option", value: "{{ any_value }}" }
```

Please note that everything is inline and I'm using an equal (=) and everything is wrapped with double quotes.