# Ansible: VPC redefine: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: ansible, vpc

I am in need of help to make it work in order to add the nat instance id as gw for private subnet inside the routing table.

Here is my vpc playbook:

### /tasks/vpc.yml

```
---
 - name: VPC | Creating an AWS VPC inside mentioned Region
   local_action:
     module: ec2_vpc
     region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
     state: present
     cidr_block: "{{ vpc_cidr_block }}"
     resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}_vpc" }
     subnets: "{{ vpc_subnets }}"
     internet_gateway: yes
     route_tables: "{{ public_subnet_rt }}"
```

=====
here is my vars/vpc.yml file:

```
---
ec2_inst_id: i-abc1432c
# Variables for VPC
vpc_name: tendo
vpc_region: ap-southeast-2
vpc_cidr_block: 172.25.0.0/16
public_cidr: 172.25.10.0/24
public_az: "{{ vpc_region}}b"
private_cidr: 172.25.20.0/24
private_az: "{{ vpc_region }}a"
nat_private_ip: 172.25.10.10

# Please don't change the variables below, until you know what you are doing
#
# Subnets Defination for VPC
vpc_subnets:
  - cidr: "{{ public_cidr }}" # Public Subnet
    az: "{{ public_az }}"
    resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}_public_subnet" }
  - cidr: "{{ private_cidr }}" # Private Subnet
    az: "{{ private_az }}"
    resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}_private_subnet" }

## Routing Table for Public Subnet
public_subnet_rt:
  - subnets:
      - "{{ public_cidr }}"
    routes:
      - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
        gw: igw
```

When I run the above playbook it work fine:

```
ansible-playbook -i 'localhost,' --connection=local site.yml -vvvv       

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************

TASK: [VPC | Creating an AWS VPC inside mentioned Region] *********************
<127.0.0.1> region=ap-southeast-2 cidr_block=172.25.0.0/16 state=present
<127.0.0.1>
<127.0.0.1>
<127.0.0.1> u'LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C /usr/bin/python /Users/arbab/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1427103212.79-152394513704427/ec2_vpc; rm -rf /Users/arbab/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1427103212.79-152394513704427/ >/dev/null 2>&1']
changed: [localhost -> 127.0.0.1] => {"changed": true, "subnets": [{"az": "ap-southeast-2b", "cidr": "172.25.10.0/24", "id": "subnet-70845e15", "resource_tags": {"Name": "tendo_public_subnet"}}, {"az": "ap-southeast-2a", "cidr": "172.25.20.0/24", "id": "subnet-8d1fdffa", "resource_tags": {"Name": "tendo_private_subnet"}}], "vpc": {"cidr_block": "172.25.0.0/16", "dhcp_options_id": "dopt-261e0244", "id": "vpc-9cea26f9", "region": "ap-southeast-2", "state": "available"}, "vpc_id": "vpc-9cea26f9"}
```

---

## Here is the problem when I redefine the VPC with the nat-instance id as gw.

```
---
 - name: NAT | NAT Route
   set_fact:
     private_subnet_rt: '{{ lookup("template", "../templates/nat_routes.json.j2") }}'

 - name: redefine vpc
   local_action:
     module: ec2_vpc
     region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
     state: present
     cidr_block: "{{ vpc_cidr_block }}"
     resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}_vpc" }
     subnets: "{{ vpc_subnets }}"
     internet_gateway: yes
     route_tables: "{{ private_subnet_rt }}"
```

Here are the content of the nat_routes.json.j2:

```
- subnets:
     - {{ public_cidr }}
  routes:
     - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
       gw: "igw"
- subnets:
     - {{ private_cidr }}
  routes:
     - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
       gw: {{ ec2_inst_id }}
```

I got this error when I run the above playbook after Creating the NAT instance:

```
TASK: [redefine vpc] **********************************************************
<127.0.0.1> region=ap-southeast-2 cidr_block=172.25.0.0/16 state=present route_tables=- subnets:
- 172.25.10.0/24
routes:
- dest: 0.0.0.0/0
gw: igw
- subnets:
- 172.25.20.0/24
routes:
- dest: 0.0.0.0/0
gw: i-abc1432c

    failed: [localhost -> 127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/arbab/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1427101746.8-192243069214182/ec2_vpc", line 2413, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Users/arbab/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1427101746.8-192243069214182/ec2_vpc", line 618, in main
        (vpc_dict, new_vpc_id, subnets_changed, changed) = create_vpc(module, vpc_conn)
      File "/Users/arbab/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1427101746.8-192243069214182/ec2_vpc", line 425, in create_vpc
        for route in rt['routes']:
    TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Can you please point me that where I am making mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Did you already try replacing `gw: "igw"` with `gw: igw` in `nat_routes.json.j2`? I don't think it would make a difference but just in case it's one of those stupid quirks of ansible.. Also as a matter of practice I always quote `"{{ vars }}"` even when ansible says it's okay not to. So I would change `gw: {{ ec2_inst_id }}` to `gw: "{{ ec2_inst_id }}"`

Comment: Just ran into the same issue more or less... no solution though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `private_subnet_rt: '{{ lookup("template", "../templates/nat_routes.json.j2") }}'` reads contents of nat_routes.json.j2 and assigns it to private_subnet_rt as a **string**. Not a YAML list of dicts as you expected.

What you need is something like:

Content of the nat_routes.json.yml:

```
private_subnet_rt:
  - subnets:
       - "{{ public_cidr }}"
    routes:
       - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
         gw: "igw"
  - subnets:
       - "{{ private_cidr }}"
    routes:
       - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
         gw: "{{ ec2_inst_id }}"
```

and then get that variable into your playbook using `include_vars`, instead of `set_fact:`.

```
- include_vars: nat_routes.json.yml
- name: redefine vpc
  local_action:
     module: ec2_vpc
     region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
     state: present
     cidr_block: "{{ vpc_cidr_block }}"
     resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}_vpc" }
     subnets: "{{ vpc_subnets }}"
     internet_gateway: yes
     route_tables: "{{ private_subnet_rt }}"
```

You can also put `nat_routes.json.yml` under sub-folders `group_vars` or `host_vars` or `roles/<role>/vars`. See [recommended folder structure](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout), in which case you don't have to do `include_vars`, ansible would do it for you implicitly based on host/group/role you're operating on.

HTH

Comment: I had a similar issue to op and this resolved it. include_vars is the way to go, and also the variable needed to be in jinja2 variable brackets...

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the value of "{{ ec2_inst_id }}" in advance and it gave me error of it, because first I am creating the vpc then, public and private subnet, after that launch the nat instance inside the public subnet and get it's id and again redefine the vpc with it's id as gateway for the private subnet hosts. hope you get my point. Thanks

Comment: @TendoLinux did you try it? It should resolve it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29178191/496289