# docker extra_host parameter expects a dictionary value for hostname, how can I use a variable?

Tags: docker, ansible

In ansible playbook docker parameter extra_host takes two parts host: ip_address. I am trying to pass the host and ipaddress in as variables. They are from prompt vars. The end result in my hosts file is: 1.2.3.4 {{server_hostname}}. Here is the code:

```
vars_prompt:
  - name: "server_ip"
    prompt: "Please enter the server IP address"
    private: no

  - name: "server_hostname"
    prompt: "Please enter the server hostname"
    private: no

tasks:    
  - name: Install Tomcat
    docker:
      image: tomcat:8.0
      pull: missing
      name: tomcat
      state: restarted
      ports: 
        - "8080:8080"
        - "443:443"
      extra_hosts:
        "{{server_hostname}}": "{{server_ip}}"
```

I am new to ansible playbook any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805976/resolve-dictionary-key-or-parameter-variable-in-ansible

Comment: It's close, but it doesn't use variables as the key or value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `server_host_ip` dict with `set_fact` before your task:

```
- set_fact:
    server_host_ip: "{'{{host_name}}':'{{host_ip}}'}"
```

And use `{{server_host_ip}}` in the `docker` module.

Comment: Can you further elaborate on how to use {{extra_hosts}} in the docker module? Show an example. When I try I get the following error:

The offending line appears to be:

          {{extra_hosts}}
           ^ here

Comment: Works... thanks! I just had to change the name of the set_fact variable extra_hosts to another non-reserved name. Example:

- set_fact: 
      server_host_ip: "{'{{server_ip}}':'{{server_hostname}}'}"

- name: Install Tomcat
  docker:
     extra_hosts:
        "{{server_hostname_ip}}"

Comment: Sorry @jbrim, I haven't tested it for reserved names. Glad that it helped you, though!