# Ansible docker_container etc_hosts with variable key

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-2.x

I've an ansible script through which I spawn a docker container and add few hosts entries to it, since etc_hosts takes key as host name and corresponding IP address. In my case I need to have both host name and IP address to be driven by some variable, for instance

```
docker_container:
name: image-name
image: image-to-be-pulled
state: started
restart_policy: always
etc_hosts:
  "{{ domain_1 }}": "{{ domain_1_ip }}"
  domain_2 : "{{ domain_2_ip }}"
  domain_3 : "{{ domain_3_ip }}"
```

When I make above configuration then it makes an entry to host file as

```
xx.xx.xx.xxx {{ domain_1 }}
```

Ideally the the host file should contain host name against the IP, can someone suggest how can i achieve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37731028/2795592

Comment: As explained in above shared link I can use set_facts to define domain and ip combination but that entry will land up in my host file?

Comment: populate a dict, say, `my_etc_hosts` in that way and set `etc_hosts: '{{my_etc_hosts}}'` when calling `docker_container`.

Comment: In my case there are multiple entries in hosts file, and in case of multiple entries it takes key value pair

Comment: Please update your question with this info: where do you store you pairs before calling `docker_container`.

Comment: In my case there are multiple host with fixed domain name but I've an entry with variable domain name and corresponding IP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker extra\_host parameter expects a dictionary value for hostname, how can I use a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729868/docker-extra-host-parameter-expects-a-dictionary-value-for-hostname-how-can-i-u)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
docker_container:
  name: image-name
  image: image-to-be-pulled
  state: started
  restart_policy: always
  etc_hosts: >
    {
      "{{ domain_1 }}": "{{ domain_1_ip }}",
      "domain_2" : "{{ domain_2_ip }}",
      "domain_3" : "{{ domain_3_ip }}"
    }
```

This will form dict-like string that ansible's templator will evaluate into dict.
Pay attention, that every item should be quoted and pairs are separated by commas.

Comment: May i know how can we handle this incase we have not defined the variables. In-short passing a default value incase variables not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I had success with...

in my play(book):

```
- vars:
    my_etc_hosts: 
      {
        "host1.example.com host1": 10.3.1.5,
        "host2.example.com host2": 10.3.1.3
      }
```

(no ">" character, compared to the accepted answer)

Separated from the playbook, the role with...

in the task:

```
- name: have the container created
  docker_container:
    etc_hosts: "{{ my_etc_hosts | default({}) }}"
```

in defaults/main.yml:

```
my_etc_hosts: {}
```

Additionally (not needed by the task above, but part of another template task):

in a template, with jinja2:

```
{% for host in my_etc_hosts | default([]) %}
    --add-host "{{ host }}":{{ my_etc_hosts[host] }} \
{% endfor %}
```

(As a plus, you see how two hostnames for one IP address can be handled: "fqdn alias1". If you instead split them into two values, they will form two lines in /etc/hosts with the same IP, which is not correct according to the man page.)