# Variable expansion does not work in Ansible Playbook when using variables as a dictionary key

Tags: ansible

I executed ansible-playbook command with following variables.

**Command**

```
ansible-playbook -vvv reconfig_vm.yml --extra-vars '{"disks":[{"name":"disk1","size_gb":"30","type":"thin","datastore":"nfs01"},{"name":"disk2","size_gb":"15","type":"thin","datastore":"nfs01"}}'
```

and then, created following Playbook.

**Playbook Content (reconfig_vm.yml)**

```
..(omitted)..
tasks:
- name: reconfig VM Disk
    local_action:
      module: vsphere_guest

           ..(omitted)..

      vm_disk:
        "{{ item.name }}":
          size_gb: "{{ item.size_gb }}"
          type: "{{ item.type }}"
          datastore: "{{ item.datastore }}"

                  ..(omitted)..

  with_items: "{{ disks }}"
```

when I run this playbook, i got following result.

**Execution Result**

```
failed: [localhost -> localhost] (item={u'size_gb': u'30', u'type':     u'thin', u'name': u'disk1', u'datastore': u'nfs01'}) => {"failed": true, "invocation": {"module_name": "vsphere_guest"}, "item": {"datastore": "nfs01", "name": "disk1", "size_gb": "30", "type": "thin"}, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File   *..(omitted)..* ansible_module_vsphere_guest.py\", line 793, in update_disks\n    hd.UnitNumber = int(disk_id)\nValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{{ item.name }}'\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

## **Question**

Execution Result indicates that "{{ item.name }}" in Playbook wasn't replaced with variables that I gave as --extra-vars.

1. Do you have any idea to expand --extra-vars as a dictionary key?
2. Do you have any alternative idea to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

## **The Code that Works Well (*Solved*)**

Thanks to Konstantin Suvorov's answer, I finally created a code which do a job I wanted to do.

**@Playbook Content (reconfig_vm.yml)**

```
tasks:
- set_fact:
    vm_disk_solo: "'{{ item.name }}':{'size_gb':'{{ item.size_gb }}','type':'{{ item.type }}','datastore':'{{ item.datastore }}'}"  
  with_items: "{{ vm.disks }}"  
  register: vm_disk_mul  

- set_fact:  
    vm_disks: "{ {{ vm_disk_mul.results | join(',',attribute='ansible_facts.vm_disk_solo') }} }"  


- name: reconfig VM Disk  
  local_action:  
    module: vsphere_guest  

    ..(omitted)..  

    vm_disk: "{{ vm_disks }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to pass extra-var in a proper format:

```
--extra-vars '{"disks":{"disk1":{"size_gb":"30","type":"thin","datastore":"nfs01"},"disk2":{"size_gb":"15","type":"thin","datastore":"nfs01"}}}'
```

And pass `vm_disk: "{{ disks }}"` without any need in looping.

If you still need to loop through your list, you need to set some dynamic facts before calling `vsphere_guest`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37731028/2795592

Comment: Your second solution works!  In my case, since "disks" has multiple element, I add a following modification.  

in Playbook Content (reconfig_vm.yml)
==============  
  
    - set_fact:
        vm_disk_solo: "'{{ item.name }}':{'size_gb':'{{ item.size_gb }}','type':'{{ item.type }}','datastore':'{{ item.datastore }}'}"  
        with_items: "{{ vm.disks }}"  
        register: vm_disk_mul  
  
    - set_fact:  
        vm_disks: "{ {{ vm_disk_mul.results | join(',',attribute='ansible_facts.vm_disk_solo') }} }"  
      
Thank you for your nice answer. Ploblem Solved.

Comment: Actually, first method you told me also works well, but It might propagate changes of "vsphere_guest" module's interface (if it happen in future), so I've choose your second method.