# Variable dictionary key not substituted

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am struggling to figure out the proper syntax to variable-ize this snippet of code:

```
vm_cidr: '10.10.0.0/24'
vm_network: FOO
vm_gateway: '10.10.0.1'
networks:
     "{{ vm_cidr }}":
       network: "{{ vm_network }}"
       gateway: "{{ vm_gateway }}"
```

The substitution for `vm_cidr` never occurs.  I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805976/resolve-dictionary-key-or-parameter-variable-in-ansible/29178191#29178191) post but I'm still struggling.  Any ideas how variable-ize this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here yo go:

```
networks: '{{ {vm_cidr:{"network":vm_network,"gateway":vm_gateway} } }}'
```

Note space at the end of dict to prevent double unnecessary double braces.

Comment: Seem to be getting closer: "fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "failed": true, "msg": "A specified parameter was not correct: spec.nicSettingMap.adapter.gateway"}"

Comment: Hmm, this is not related to the question I guess. You can print `networks` with debug, it should give you exactly what you asked.

Comment: Nevermind, this worked perfectly!  For whatever reason in my tinkering I had double and single quotes around the value for vm_gateway.  Thanks!!!

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Why do you point out this space? Just aesthetics? Because, using `}} }}` or `}}}}` at the end does not change the way code works, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just assume that the scalar "`vm_cidr`" (without spaces at the back and front) is the same as "`vm_cidr`" within `{{` and `}}`.

You should try:

```
vm_cidr: '10.10.0.0/24'
vm_network: FOO
vm_gateway: '10.10.0.1'
networks:
     "{{vm_cidr}}":
       network: "{{vm_network}}"
       gateway: "{{vm_gateway}}"
```

Comment: The error was: netaddr.core.AddrFormatError: invalid IPNetwork "{{vm_cidr}}"

Comment: @Anthon Could you explain in a bit more details? I always thought they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `|` character to create a multi-line scalar

```
vm_cidr: '10.10.0.0/24'
vm_network: FOO
vm_gateway: '10.10.0.1'
networks: |
    {
        "{{vm_cidr}}": {
           network: "{{vm_network}}"
           gateway: "{{vm_gateway}}"
        }
    }
```