# Getting variable values from url

Tags: ansible

i am new to ansible and i am trying to achieve the following,

This is the sample playbook, here i am creating a reg key called "test" under HKLM:\SOFTWARE\myapp\Desk\ and i am adding 2 entries with items called hello and hi and i am assigning single same value "world" to both hello and hi.

i want to get the value for hello and hi from some file which will be stored in a repository or some url ..the value will be different for hello and hi.. is this possible ?

```
---
 - hosts: web
   tasks:
    - name: Create and add reg entries
      win_regedit:
       path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\myapp\Desk\Test
       entry: "{{ item }}"
       data: world
       type: string
       state: present
      with_items:
         - hello
         - hi
```

Update:

Some improvement here for a newbie, i am able to iterate through with_items with key value , but i want to have a file with key:value and i want the ansible to iterate through all the left side keys and create them and also fill them with the right side values..that is the entry in win_Regedit should have key and data should have values

```
---
 - hosts: web
   tasks:
    - name: Create and add reg entries
      win_regedit:
       path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\myapp\Desk\Test
       entry: "{{ item.regkey }}"
       data: "{{ item.regvalue}}"
       type: string
       state: present
      with_items:
         - regkey: hello
           regvalue: world
         - regkey: hi
           regvalue: universe
```

Comment: did i ask anything wrong? :( i should have asked how to achieve this.. can you please elaborate this

Comment: Glad we could help. If you feel an answer helped solve your question, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers

Comment: although i am not using it, i appreciate the help you provided.thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include variable from some file, you can use the `include_vars` module:

```
include_vars:
        file: vars.yml
```

**Edit** What you want to do is probably something like below (did not try the win_regedit as I don't have any windows node):

Create a vars.yml:

```
---
var1: 'key1'
var2: 'key2'
d1: "{
  '{{var1}}': 'val1',
  '{{var2}}': 'val2'
}"
```

Then launch the following playbook (see the with_dict statement):

```
 ---
    - hosts: localhost
      remote_user: my_user

      tasks:
        - name: pull var_file
          url: http://example.com/path/to/vars
          dest: /path/to/vars.yml
          mode: 0440 
        - name: include_vars
          include_vars:
            /path/to/vars.yml
        - name: Create and add reg entries
          win_regedit:
          path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\myapp\Desk\Test
          entry: "{{ item.key }}"
          data: "{{ item.value}}"
          type: string
          state: present
          with_dict: "{{d1}}"
```

Kudos to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29178191/4121573) for the `with_dict` trick

Comment: is it possible to have a file in format of key:value pair and i want to store them in a url and i want to fetch them and use win_Regedit to create key and value as it is

Comment: @windowws About the key:value pair, isn't that what is shown in the vars.yml above? (e.g. var1 is the key, val1 is the value) What does storing in a url means? (is it a REST endpoint, is it a webpage...) About win_regedit, I cannot say anything as having zero knowledge regarding windows (you might want to check the command module that might help though I don't know the behavior on a windows node)

Comment: thanks for replying, yes i want to have a file in key:value format and i will store it in a url, a webpage, it can be a html or json..  and your example is correct but instead of "Value of var1" i want just var1 there and that too it should be pulled in automatically, i wont give the key here..i hope you got my question, whatever is in that file should be created

Comment: @windowws Then I would simply add a task using the `get_url` module to pull a file from your url before applying the include_vars and whatever other tasks rely on it. See the playbook I edited above.

Comment: Updated my question, basically i dont want to use with_items for every entry and i want to fetch that from text file or json or html

Comment: @windowws What is not clear about the include_vars module? Because the module is exactly pulling from a yaml formatted text file pairs of key/value

Comment: in win_Regedit there is something called entry and there is something called data, both of them needs an input from us, if i have a key:value the key should become entry and value should become data, i am kind of confused in achieving this

Comment: @windowws I think I get it, you also need the key value right? I edited my post above

Comment: it looks like we are close but far yet :( the var.yml should be created by ansible not by me, i will have a text file with only var1:val1, var2:val2  but i should be able to pull it and parse it to create var.yml file ..

Comment: @windowws In that case, I would try with a template file to fill the necessary value (though I am not sure it would work, and that's the only trick I know of to get the key's value): http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html

Comment: Thanks for taking time and helping me out...you are awesome..my next step is to ask questions about templates :(

Answer (score 1):

Use [uri](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/uri_module.html) module.

```yaml
 ---
    - hosts: localhost
      remote_user: my_user

      tasks:
        - name: pull var_file
          uri:
            url: http://example.com/path/to/vars
            method: GET
            return_content: yes
          register: vars_from_url
        - name: Create and add reg entries
          win_regedit:
          path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\myapp\Desk\Test
          entry: "{{ item.key }}"
          data: "{{ item.value}}"
          type: string
          state: present
          with_dict: "{{ vars_from_url.content }}"
```